# Global variables, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

I have the following code

```
oss = $("#us");
mainLogo = $("#mainLogo");
container = $(".container");

$(document).ready(function(){
    oss.hide();
    oss.fadeIn(1000);
    mainLogo.hide();
    mainLogo.fadeIn(1000);
    container.find("#images").hide();
    container.find("#images").slideDown();
})
$(oss).click(function(){
    container.fadeOut();
})
```

The problem I have is that I can't seem to access the variables outside. I've tried window.varName, just writing var infront etc. But the compiler seems to just skip it and thus not do anything.

Comment: Are these scripts loaded before the body portion of the page? If so, `$("anyselector")` will always be an empty jQuery object before the page has loaded.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense..I don't have much experience with coding webpages, it's alot of fun though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following piece of code does the same you are trying to accomplish. This way you declare the global variables: oss, mainLogo and container outside the scope  of document.ready().

```
var oss;
var mainLogo;
var container;

$(document).ready(function(){

    oss = $("#us");
    mainLogo = $("#mainLogo");
    container = $(".container");

    oss.hide();
    oss.fadeIn(1000);
    mainLogo.hide();
    mainLogo.fadeIn(1000);
    container.find("#images").hide();
    container.find("#images").slideDown();


    oss.click(function(){
        container.fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: So the logic is that you create global variables then insert values, strings and so on. Also the $(document).ready() I've understood correctly activates, called upon, when the webpage is loaded? Thus leading to the oss.click being callable?

Comment: In this case yes since the elements are available when the DOM is loaded. And thats why the $(document).ready() is needed to initialise further events on elements.